# Best way of persisting the processing status of each individual item

Tags: spring-batch

In my project I am reading the data for DB table using StoredProcedure reader and calling an API to process and then saving the output using writer. I need to maintain the processing status as Processed or Error for each record that I am reading. As of now I am using the writer to update the input table column STATUS to P (Processed) or E(Error) and add logs the in case of any error to LOGS column.

Can you please suggest if this is the efficient way to maintain the processing status of each record. Does Spring batch provides any default implementation for same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Spring Batch does not provide a "default implementation" for such a requirement.

That said, a flag on each item as you did is a reasonable way to address your requirement in my opinion.

Comment: As always thanks for your quick response.